# batch request for single objectID swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to update single entity in swift with help of batch request. It works perfect to update all the entities. Is it possible to update single entity using it's objectID?
Here is the example code:

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext    
 let batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Outlays")
 batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["purchase": self.purchase.text!]
 batchRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectsCountResultType
 do {
   let results = try managedContext.executeRequest(batchRequest)  as! NSBatchUpdateResult
   print(" \(results.result) results changed")
 } catch {
   print(error)
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not need updating a single entity (`NSManagedObject`) in a batch request.

The easiest way is just to set the new value on your Outlays objects. Of course they have to be of type `NSManagedObject`. Call `saveContext` on your `NSManagedObjectContext` afterwards:

```
myOutlay.text = "changed"
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext 
var error: NSError? = nil
managedContext.save(&error)
```

If you only have the `NSManagedObjectID` of your `NSManagedObject`, it's required  to get it from the Datastore first:

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext 
var myOutlay: Outlays = managedObjectContext.existingObjectWithID(outlayManagedID, error: nil) as? Outlays
myOutlay.text = "changed"
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext 
var error: NSError? = nil
managedContext.save(&error)
```